# Box with adaptive length

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, width

When I want to put formulas into boxes, I like the box to adapt to the length of my formula. For example, I don't want to put `$1+1=2$` in a very large box. To address this, I use the command `\encadrer` (it requires the `calc` package and the `ifthen` package) which is included in the preamble of the following minimal example :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

%\encadrer:
\newlength\lenbox
\newcommand{\encadrer}[1]{

\linethickness{2pt}
\setlength\lenbox{\widthof{#1}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\lenbox}
#1
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center} 
}


\begin{document}

\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$}

\end{document}
```

But this command doesn't work for multiple lines. For example, if I put

```
\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$ \\ and \\ $1+1=2$}
```

in the previous example, the box becomes larger. In this example, I would like the length of the box to be max(`\widthof{$1+1+1=3$}`, `\widthof{$1+1=2$}`). I thought of something :
If the argument of `\encadrer` is of the form : `string1 \\ string2 \\ ... \\ stringN`, I can use the `xstring` package to extract all the strings between `\\` and use a loop to define something like that : (in pseudocode)

```
set lenbox to 0
for i from 1 to N
  set lenbox to max(lenbox,\widthof{stringi})
end for
```

But it feels complicated and I wonder if there is another solution. If I on the right track, can someone help me convert this pseudocode to LaTeX code ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: BTW, you do not need package `calc`. `\setlength\lenbox{\widthof{#1}}` can be replaced by `\settowidth\lenbox{#1}`.

Comment: I didn't know that ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)'s similarly-named `varwidth` environment provides this functionality by default, setting a box of "natural width" if the width is smaller than what is specified:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth

%\encadrer:
\newcommand{\encadrer}[1]{{%
  \centering
  \fbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
      \centering #1%
    \end{varwidth}%
  }
  \par}%
}


\begin{document}

\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$}

\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$ \\ and \\ $1+1=2$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank your very much ! I didn't know this package. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid all measurements:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

%\encadrer:
\newcommand{\encadrer}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    #1
    \end{varwidth}%
  }
  \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$}

\encadrer{$1+1+1=3$ \\ and \\ $1+1=2$}

\end{document}
```

Note that the parameter for the frame thickness is `\fboxsep`; setting it inside the `center` environment ensures it will revert to the previous value. However, 2pt is really too much, as you'll see in the image.

Note also that I protected some end-of-lines in order to avoid spurious spaces. It's not necessary to have `%` after `\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}` and after `#1` because it those positions the spaces will be ignored, but they aren't in `\fbox`, in general.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your `\encadrer` command includes a lot of extra white space due to missing `%` at the ends of lines, apart from the problem with multiple line entries.

I think you want

```
\newcommand{\encadrer}[1]{\fbox{$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}$}}
```